# Copy file with security using robocopy

Tags: cmd, robocopy

Hi I need to copy a file with timestamp and security from other server. I copied it but the security is not same. The specific user is grant to modify the file. However the copied file missing this specific user.

I tried the below commands

```
robocopy \\sourceServer\c$\Test \\desSever\c$\Test "new From.txt"  /SEC /R:1 /W:1 /NP /TEE

robocopy \\sourceServer\c$\Test \\desSever\c$\Test "new From.txt" /COPY:DATSO /R:1 /W:1 /NP /TEE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `/COPYALL` or `/COPY:DATSOU`.

If you are copying/replacing existing files, you may also need to use the flag `/SECFIX`. Otherwise, make sure to totally remove the files and parent directories so that NTFS permissions can be copied over fresh.

One more thing: there may be conditions that robocopy does not copy inherited permissions. Check to see if the permissions are on the file/directory itself, or if they are being inherited from a parent.

For more information:
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/367948-robocopy-to-inherit-destination-folder-permissions-to-new-child-folders-files

https://conetrix.com/blog/robocopy-secfix-parameter

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/b36748cd-14d1-47a5-9fb6-878ca93ad6fc/robocopy-not-copying-ntfs-permissions